# is there a unified term for the open-source and managed services in our HLD?

Tags: open-source, microservices, software-as-a-service, high-level

I'm preparing a session on our product's HLD (High-Level Design) for newbies.
It's a microservices-based system that includes several self-managed open-source projects & other managed services (e.g. Kafka, Redis, etc.)

I want to address those services in my presentation in a unified manner - services that are not internally developed and maintained but still play a part in the overall system environment.

Is there such a term\concept, which I can also further read about?

Comment: Third party components?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> services that are not internally developed and maintained but still play a part in the overall system environment

Components/parts/whatever that your team/company/etc. did not develop themselves but got from another party (could be another team within the same company, depending on your scope), are commonly referred to as "third party" components/parts/whatever.